# ValueError: Attempt to convert a value Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to prepare my.CSV file for deep learning. currently, I am trying to read data from the CSV file. but got an error that cant understand.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

csv_path = "/Users/dean/Desktop/AI TECNOMATIX EXCEL/cartest1.csv"

def DESAI_map(name, platform, year):
    return {'MachineAvailability': MA, "MachineEntranceLocked": MEnL, "MachineExitLocked": MExL, "MachineMTTR": MTTR, "StatNumIn": SNI, "StatNumOut": SNO}

DESAI_dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
    filenames=csv_path,
    record_defaults=[tf.Variable,tf.string, tf.string, tf.Variable,tf.Variable,tf.Variable([1900], dtype=tf.int32)],
    select_cols=[1, 2, 3,4,5,6],
    field_delim=",",
    header=True)

DESAI_dataset = DESAI_dataset.filter(lambda MA:MA<=99, MEnL, MExL,MTTR,SNI,SNO)
DESAI_dataset = DESAI_dataset.map(map_func=DESAI_map)
DESAI_dataset = DESAI_dataset.batch(1)

for data in DESAI_dataset:
    tf.print(data)  # Print : {'Name': [Wii Sports], 'Platform': [Wii], 'Year': [2006]}
    break



ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.VariableV1'>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.VariableMetaclass'>) to a Tensor.
```

### Test data

```
name,MachineAvailability,MachineEntranceLocked,MachineExitLocked,MachineMTTR,StatNumIn,StatNumOut 
XX,100,FALSE,FALSE,0,0,0
XY,100,FALSE,FALSE,0,0,0 
XX,100,FALSE,FALSE,0,2,2
XX,100,FALSE,FALSE,0,2,2
```

### Stack trace

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)  in  13 select_cols=[1, 2, 3,4,5,6], 14 field_delim=",", ---> 15 header=True) 16 17 DESAI_dataset = DESAI_dataset.filter(lambda MA:MA<=99, MEnL, MExL,MTTR,SNI,SNO)
>
> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value () with an unsupported type () to a Tensor.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would be helpful if you can share a sample dataset. As well as the full stack trace.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ab749f237be3> in <module>
     13     select_cols=[1, 2, 3,4,5,6],
     14     field_delim=",",
---> 15     header=True)
     16 
     17 DESAI_dataset = DESAI_dataset.filter(lambda MA:MA<=99, MEnL, MExL,MTTR,SNI,SNO)

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.VariableV1'>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.VariableMetaclass'>) to a Tensor.

Comment: Sample of data set

Comment: name MachineAvailability MachineEntranceLocked MachineExitLocked MachineMTTR StatNumIn StatNumOut
XX 100 FALSE FALSE 0 0 0
XY 100 FALSE FALSE 0 0 0
XX 100 FALSE FALSE 0 2 2
XX 100 FALSE FALSE 0 2 2

Comment: would be clearer if you can post the data in the question itself (with proper structure - so that anyone can just paste the data and reproduce the problem.).

Comment: Also, what are these `MA,MEnL, MExL,MTTR,SNI,SNO`? They are not defined in the code you posted.

Comment: Ma just a short cut of MachineAvailability and so on

Answer (score 0):

The error you're coming across is caused by the way you have defined your dataset reader. The correct way to define it would be,

```
DESAI_dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
    filenames=csv_path,
    record_defaults=[0,"False", "False", 0, 0, 0],
    select_cols=[1, 2, 3,4,5,6],
    field_delim=",",
    header=True)
```

The idea of having `record_default` is that if some data is corrupted (or cannot be read for some reason) it will be replaced by what's found in `record_defaults`. So having `tf.Variable` as the record default doesn't make sense as the need to be `Tensors` or just plain python values. You can have a read about what is accepted for `record_defaults` in [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset).

Now, I commented out the following lines, as you haven't shared some of the variables (e.g. MA, MEnL, etc.). But I'll update my answer as needed.

```
DESAI_dataset = DESAI_dataset.filter(lambda MA:MA<=99, MEnL, MExL,MTTR,SNI,SNO)
DESAI_dataset = DESAI_dataset.map(map_func=DESAI_map)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just have the following question. In the record_defaults, is False considered boolean as I do have some output True and some False? What about the 0 is it sat as defaults or it is a changeable variable based on data input.

Comment: As I explained, `record_default` is constant. It will replace any unreadable entries in your data. So the short answer is, no. You cannot change it based on data as the whole point of having record_defaults is to help when you can't read data.